# Error while exporting from ms sql to access

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, export

I am trying to export the following data in the query from ms sql server to access, it says an error "Field wkid already exists in the table results"

when i try to execute the same using sql query analyser, its not giving any error.i am getting the results in the grid

```
Select a.wkid,a.stid,a.pfid,pf.pfname,a.modid,mm.md,a.catid,
[sp],revenue,profit,wkid  from
(select stid,modid,pfid,catid,
[sp],revenue,profit,wkid 
from dbo.modspsal
where wkid >= 200934 and wkid <= 201033 and 
catid in (20001,20002,20003,20004,20005,20006)) as a
left join mml mm on 
mm.modid=a.modid
left join (select distinct pfid,[pf name] as pfname from mml) as pf
on pf.pfid=a.pfid
order by a.wkid,stid,catid,a.pfid,a.modid
```

Comment: having code that is formatted a little better makes it easier to see what @astander points out in his answer.  sql query analyser doesn't care if column names are duplicated, try _SELECT 1 as A, 1 AS A, 1 AS A_ but if you are trying to create a new table in Access, I'll bet that it cares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are exporting to excel you require to have unique column names. You have wkid specified 2.

```
Select  a.wkid,--HERE
        a.stid,
        a.pfid,
        pf.pfname,
        a.modid,
        mm.md,
        a.catid, 
        [sp],
        revenue,
        profit,
        wkid  --HERE
from    (
            select  stid,
                    modid,
                    pfid,
                    catid, 
                    [sp],
                    revenue,
                    profit,
                    wkid  
            from    dbo.modspsal 
            where   wkid >= 200934 
            and     wkid <= 201033 
            and     catid in (20001,20002,20003,20004,20005,20006)
        ) as a  left join 
        mml mm  ON  mm.modid=a.modid  left join 
        (
            select  distinct 
                    pfid,
                    [pf name] as pfname 
            from mml
        ) as pf on  pf.pfid=a.pfid 
order by a.wkid,stid,catid,a.pfid,a.modid
```

Remove the last wkid and you should be fine.